# Reachability and IPv6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipv6, reachability

One of my project uses the Apple's Reachability class in order to be monitor the network state and be notified in case of changes.

After reading [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW27) about supporting IPv6 I was wondering if were to be made to this class to make it work with IPv6.

I set up an IPv6 network following [the same article](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16) and everything seems to work fine but maybe there is an issue with the setup.

**Is the part of the Reachability class checking the Internet connection working with IPv6 as it is now or does it need some changes?**

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Is that create problem if i am not updating reachability library ? And what will happen if my app is already uploaded with old library ? 
\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer from Apple itself (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/719/ at ~10:30 - though I would recommend to watch the video in full - or at least look through at the key points here: http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2015/06/video-of-apple-wwdc-session-about-ipv6-and-ios-9-now-available-and-some-screenshots/):

Just Try The Connection.

A copy paste from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW25 which reiterates this:

> **Connect Without Preflight**
>
> The Reachability APIs (see SCNetworkReachability Reference) are
> intended for diagnostic purposes after identifying a connectivity
> issue. Many apps incorrectly use these APIs to proactively check for
> an Internet connection by calling the
> SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress method and passing it an IPv4
> address of 0.0.0.0, which indicates that there is a router on the
> network. However, the presence of a router doesn’t guarantee that an
> Internet connection exists. In general, avoid preflighting network
> reachability. Just try to make a connection and gracefully handle
> failures. If you must check for network availability, avoid calling
> the SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress method. Call the
> SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName method and pass it a hostname
> instead.
>
> Some apps also pass the SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress method
> an IPv4 address of 169.254.0.0, a self-assigned link-local address, to
> check for an active Wi-Fi connection. To check for Wi-Fi or cellular
> connectivity, look for the network reachability flag
> kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN instead.

Comment: Is that create problem if i am not updating reachability library ? And what will happen if my app is already uploaded with old library ?

Comment: If you avoid calling the old routines, then you will just have some dead code, which probably isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar doubt regarding IPv6 and Reachability class. Apple has asked in their docs to provide support for IPv6 types also like `(struct in_addr6, AF_INET6, struct sockaddr_in6 etc)` but the class seem to be not updated yet to have these types. This is the doubt that I am having. I am yet to try IPv6 tests but just observed while doing the static code checks. Some changes might be required.

[Reachability.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_8)

```
+ (instancetype)reachabilityForInternetConnection
{
    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;

    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));

    zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);

    zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    return [self reachabilityWithAddress:&zeroAddress];
}
```

Comment: If you must check for network availability, avoid calling the `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress` method. Call the `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName` method and pass it a hostname instead. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html