# iPv6 support for reachability Class

Tags: ios, ios9, ipv6

I am using reachability class in my application to monitor networkstate. 
Apple has mentioned in their docs to provide support for IPv6 types.

I found that some iPV4 types are using in reachability class. 
I have searched for new reachability class and did not find..
is there any new class for check iPv6 network reachability state.?

```
   + (Reachability*) reachabilityForLocalWiFi;
    {
        struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
        bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
        localWifiAddress.sin_len = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
        localWifiAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0
        localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM);
        Reachability* retVal = [self reachabilityWithAddress: &localWifiAddress];
        if(retVal!= NULL)
        {
            retVal->localWiFiRef = YES;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: I've posted a reply to what I think is a duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938536/reachability-and-ipv6/37057558#37057558

Answer (score 1):

Found this [**on Apple's forums**](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13609). It describe the best the current status of this issue:

> **Q:** "We are using reachabilityForLocalWiFi from reachability class? I
>   notice  reachabilityForLocalWiFi method is using
>   reachabilityWithAddress (local ip address)? I am wondering how will it
>   work for the ivp6 address? Currently it works for ipv4 address."
>
> **A:** (By "the Eskimo"): "I don’t think that will be a problem.  Even if
>   the device only has IPv6 connectivity to the outside world, it should
>   still be able to get to link-local IPv4 addresses (169.254/16), which
>   is what +reachabilityForLocalWiFi uses."