# App rejected due to connected to an IPv6 network to ensure it will launch without crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, ipv6, ipv4

My app is contentiously rejected by reviewers.They gives me below reason.

**Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch without crashing.**

I've used objective-c and the api which I used is in php. Also I have used `NSURLSession` and `NSURLConnection` for calling the API's.

I'm not using `AFnetworking` .I have done lots of RNDs from last two days.
Can anyone suggest me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: are you using `Recahbility` class to check internet connectivity?? or your any thirdparty library is using `Rechability` ?

Comment: Yeas. I'm using Reachability version 2.2

Comment: Have you tested your app on an IPv6 network?

Comment: Yeas.I've tested.

Comment: Did apple send you a crash report?  Have you erased your device or at least removed your app before installing and testing?

Comment: Yeas paulw11. I've done all the things which i found on google,

Comment: @Lion is there some thing wrong in Reachability?

Comment: @KiranBhoraniya Yes check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938536/reachability-and-ipv6

Answer (score 1):

If you are using old `Rechability` class then replace it with latest one because apple's old `Rechability` class is not compatible with `ipv6` only network. You can get latest `Rechability` class from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html). I am not sure that this is only issue but in many cases ipv6 issue found because of old `rechabilty class`.

And you should refer [this apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html) also!

Comment: Okie Lion..I'll replace the rechability class.