# App rejected due to crash on iPv6

Tags: swift3, crash, app-store-connect, ipv6

Recently my app is rejected due to a crash on iPv6 network. But symbolicating the crash report , I am unable to crete that crash even on iPv6.

> Apple says: Your app crashed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1 connected to
>   an IPv6 network when we tapped on any of the new articles in the news
>   tab. This occurred when your app was used:
>   - On Wi-Fi We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue

Symbolicated crash report is :

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
Thread 0
Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000010083e2ac
**swift_unknownRetain (__hidden#18966_:380) 1   *******                
    0x0000000100026d68 **NewsDetailViewController.getNewsDetail() -> ()**
(NewsDetailViewController.swift:0) 2   ******                     
    0x0000000100025228 NewsDetailViewController.viewDidLoad() -> ()
(NewsDetailViewController.swift:0)
```

Method:

```
func getNewsDetail(){

    //Checking reachability via apple Reachability class
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus: Int = 
    reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().rawValue
    if networkStatus == 0{return}

    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    //WebServices class uses simple NSURLSession tasks
    WebServices(type: .get).startRequest(url: AppUrl.NEWS_DETAIL + 
        (newsDetail?.newsId ?? ""), info: nil) { (response) in

        if let data = response?["data"] as?Dictionary<String,String>{
           self.setDescription(desc: data["description"])
        }else{
            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

}
```

Now after struggling a lot I have been unable to find crash. Is it something that my server must support iPv6? If so, why all other apis are working and the crash is only on this api. Please suggest me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276207/app-rejected-due-to-connected-to-an-ipv6-network-to-ensure-it-will-launch-withou?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes I have checked  that and I have latest Reachability class as that post suggests but still it persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded it again without any change in code and it approved, it's strange though. This has happened to me in two apps.

Comment: i got stuck with same issue, whats the solution.